# "memory" of deleted rows from dataframe remain in new dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

I am not really sure what is going on here so the title might not be the most accurate, moderator, please feel free to modify it to be more descriptive if you think it is needed. I have several questions about various basic outputs, I hope this is allowed.

Anyway, I copied this data frame from pdf in order to go through an example:

"Exam 1" "Exam 2" Quiz

2.0 a 4.0

3.3 a 3.7

4.0 b 4.0

2.3 d 3.3

2.3 a 3.3

3.3 e 4.0

As

I accidently copied "As", which is part of the sentence in the pdf after the data frame. I used following code to import it:

```
df<-read.delim("clipboard", sep=" ", as.is=F)
df

  Exam.1 Exam.2 Quiz
1    2.0      a  4.0
2    3.3      a  3.7
3    4.0      b  4.0
4    2.3      d  3.3
5    2.3      a  3.3
6    3.3      e  4.0
7     As          NA
```

question 1.) Here I dont understand, why is there no NA listed for Exam.2?

At this point, I realised my mistake and in order to remove the last row, I produced a following code and here is where the things got weird:

```
df1<-df[1:((nrow(df))-1),]
summary(df1)

Exam.1  Exam.2      Quiz      
 2.0:1    :0    Min.   :3.300  
 2.3:2   a:3    1st Qu.:3.400  
 3.3:2   b:1    Median :3.850  
 4.0:1   d:1    Mean   :3.717  
 As :0   e:1    3rd Qu.:4.000  
                Max.   :4.000
```

Question 2) I understand why df2$Exam.1 column is factor, because it inherited class from df$Exam.1, what I don't understand is why summary of df1 still lists "As" as something existing? Is information about factor levels coded into "parent"  dataframe and R simply draws this from original df? Also, where can I read more about this?

Question 3) Finally, why is there " :0" listed as first row of summary output for the df1$Exam.2 My best guess is, there cant be NA value for factors so it just leaves blank? And than leaves said blank as a part of the data frame?

Edit:
Even after I use rm(df) so all information about parent df should be gone from the environment, I am still getting "As" listed in the summary of df1

Comment: 1) It's read as either `""` or `" "`; not `NA`.

Comment: 2) The factor level is retained no matter if you subset. You can read about `factors` here: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html

Comment: 3) See 1. `NA` values can exist for factors but it was not read as such.

Comment: Ad Edit) Check `droplevels()` :-)

Comment: You know, you could answer these in a form of a answer and we can close this than?

Comment: "At this point, I realised my mistake" If that happens it is always best to fix and repeat the data import.

Comment: Yeah, usually. But I worked with R for years as analyst and I feel that I stopped progressing due to always taking easy way out of problems instead of coding my way out and understanding why things are the way they are. This is from a book, example data, not work related, so I decided to push through it.

Comment: As an exercise this is fair, but in general fixing wrongly read data is bad practice, for reproducible data I would also suggest you use `read.table(header = TRUE, text=)` instead of reading from the clipboard so you will have reproducible code.